# vmlaunch simple crash ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, x86-64, virtualization

I am porting VMLaunch simple to ubuntu 16.04, the code is at https://github.com/vishmohan/vmlaunch. And modified the vmlaunch_simple.c to make it *almost* work in ubuntu 16.04.
When I load the module (KVM and KVM_intel have been unloaded), the 'insmod vmlaunch_simple.ko' hang, where kexec/kdump chimed in and the host is rebooted.
After reboot, the crash log showed below,

```
[  866.579251] vmlaunch_simple: module verification failed: signature `.....`
[  866.581183] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000005
[  866.584255] IP: [<0000000000000005>] 0x5
[  866.585750] PGD 0
[  866.586562] Oops: 0010 [#1] SMP
[  866.619897] task: ffff8800b99cee00 ti: ffff880234138000 task.ti: ffff880234138000
[  866.622615] RIP: 0010:[<0000000000000005>]  [<0000000000000005>] 0x5
[  866.625045] RSP: 0018:ffff88023413bc40  EFLAGS: 00010286
[  866.626989] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000001200000018 RCX: 0000000000000006
[  866.629643] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000246 RDI: ffff88023fc8cbf0
[  866.632236] RBP: fffa322300000001 R08: 656e6f44203e313c R09: 0000000000000801
[  866.634830] R10: ffffea0008d1a600 R11: 0000000000000801 R12: ffff880035cfda40
[  866.637502] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffffffc0421868 R15: ffffffffc0424bc0
[  866.640104] FS:  ffffffffe4901700(0000) GS:ffff88023fc80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  866.643040] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  866.645162] CR2: 0000000000000005 CR3: 0000000233356000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
[  866.647807] Stack:
[  866.648576]  0000000000004402 000001e75074c4cf 000001e75076e27f 5076e27f5074c4cf
[  866.651460]  000001e7000001e7 00000000cc0ba018 ffffffff81e0f040 ffff88023413bcf8
[  866.654341]  ffffffff810003e3 ffffea0008ccd300 ffff88023413bcd0 0000000000000282
[  866.657224] Call Trace:
[  866.658152]  [<ffffffff810003e3>] ? do_one_initcall+0xb3/0x1f0
[  866.660315]  [<ffffffff811cfeb3>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x183/0x1f0
[  866.663309]  [<ffffffff81171c37>] ? do_init_module+0x5f/0x1cf
[  866.666023]  [<ffffffff810efdba>] ? load_module+0x225a/0x28b0
[  866.668854]  [<ffffffff810ec3c0>] ? __symbol_put+0x60/0x60
[  866.671464]  [<ffffffff811f6120>] ? kernel_read+0x50/0x80
[  866.674031]  [<ffffffff810f0654>] ? SYSC_finit_module+0xb4/0xe0
[  866.676784]  [<ffffffff810f069e>] ? SyS_finit_module+0xe/0x10
[  866.679455]  [<ffffffff818046db>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x6a
[  866.682455] Code:  Bad RIP value.
[  866.684408] RIP  [<0000000000000005>] 0x5
[  866.686492]  RSP <ffff88023413bc40>
[  866.688334] CR2: 0000000000000005
```

The source code,

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <asm/tlbflush.h>
#include <asm/desc.h>
#include "vmxon_simple.h"

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

#define MYPAGE_SIZE 4096
#define VMX_BASIC_MSR 0x480
#define FEATURE_CONTROL_MSR 0x3A
#define CPUID_VMX_BIT 5

bool alloc_failure = false;
int vmx_msr_addr = VMX_BASIC_MSR;
int feature_control_msr_addr = FEATURE_CONTROL_MSR;
u64    vmx_rev_id = 0;
int vmxon_success = 0;
int vmxoff_success = 0;
int vmptrld_success = 0;
int vmclear_success = 0;
int vmwrite_success = 0;
int vmread_success = 0;
int vmlaunch_success = 0;
char *vmxon_region;
char *vmcs_guest_region;
char *io_bitmap_a_region;
char *io_bitmap_b_region;
char *msr_bitmap_region;
char *virtual_apic_page;

long int vmxon_phy_region = 0;
long int vmcs_phy_region = 0;
long int io_bitmap_a_phy_region = 0;
long int io_bitmap_b_phy_region = 0;
long int msr_bitmap_phy_region = 0;
long int virtual_apic_page_phy_region = 0;

unsigned long value;
long int rflags_value = 0;
u16 tr_sel; //selector for task register

static int  do_vmclear(void);
static int  do_vmptrld(void);
static void vmxon_exit(void);
static u64  do_vmread(unsigned long field);

u16         host_gdtr[5], host_idtr[5];

#define MY_VMX_VMXON_RAX         ".byte 0xf3, 0x0f, 0xc7, 0x30"
#define MY_VMX_VMPTRLD_RAX       ".byte 0x0f, 0xc7, 0x30"
#define MY_VMX_VMCLEAR_RAX       ".byte 0x66, 0x0f, 0xc7, 0x30"
#define MY_VMX_VMLAUNCH          ".byte 0x0f, 0x01, 0xc2"
#define MY_VMX_VMRESUME          ".byte 0x0f, 0x01, 0xc3"
#define MY_VMX_VMREAD_RDX_RAX    ".byte 0x0f, 0x78, 0xd0"
#define MY_VMX_VMWRITE_RAX_RDX   ".byte 0x0f, 0x79, 0xd0"
#define MY_VMX_VMXOFF            ".byte 0x0f, 0x01, 0xc4"
#define MY_VMX_VMCALL            ".byte 0x0f, 0x01, 0xc1"
#define MY_HLT                 ".byte 0xf4"

static u64 do_vmread(unsigned long field)
{
    u64 value = 0;

    vmread_success = 1;
    asm volatile("vmread %1, %0\n"
            : "=a"(value) : "d"(field) : "cc");
    asm volatile("jbe vmread_fail\n");
    asm volatile("jmp vmread_finish\n");
    asm volatile("vmread_fail:\n");
    printk("   # vmread(0x%lX) failed\n", field);
    printk("   # RFLAGS: 0x%lX\n", rflags_value);
    vmread_success = 0;
    asm volatile("vmread_finish:\n");
    return value;
}

static int do_vmxon(void)
{
    vmxon_success = 1;
    smp_mb();
    asm volatile( "vmxon %0\n"           \
            "jbe vmxon_fail\n"     \
            "jmp vmxon_finish\n"   \
            "vmxon_fail:     \n"   \
            "   movl  $0, vmxon_success \n"\
            "vmxon_finish: \n"
            :
            : "m"(vmxon_phy_region)
            : "memory", "cc");
    if (vmxon_success == 0) {
        printk("[i] vmxon has failed! VT-X is busy by other VMM.\n");
    }

    return !(vmxon_success);
}

static int do_vmptrld(void)
{
    asm volatile("vmptrld %0\n"
            :
            : "m"(vmcs_phy_region)
            : "cc", "memory");
    asm volatile("jbe vmptrld_fail\n");
    vmptrld_success = 1;
    asm volatile("jmp vmptrld_finish\n"
            "vmptrld_fail:\n");
    vmptrld_success = 0;
    pr_err("[i] vmptrld has failed!\n");
    asm volatile("vmptrld_finish:\n");

    return !vmptrld_success;
}

static int do_vmclear(void)
{
    asm volatile ("vmclear %1 \n"
            : : "a"(&vmcs_phy_region), "m"(vmcs_phy_region)
            : "cc", "memory");
    asm volatile("jbe vmclear_fail");
    vmclear_success = 1;
    asm volatile("jmp vmclear_finish\n"
            "vmclear_fail:\n");
    vmclear_success = 0;
    pr_err("[i] vmclear has failed!\n");
    asm volatile("vmclear_finish:\n");
    printk("<1> vmclear done!\n");

    return !(vmclear_success);
}

/*do vmxoff*/
static int do_vmxoff(void)
{
    asm volatile("vmxoff\n" : : : "cc");
    asm volatile("jbe vmxoff_fail\n");
    vmxoff_success = 1;
    asm volatile("jmp vmxoff_finish\n");
    asm volatile("vmxoff_fail:\n");
    vmxoff_success = 0;
    pr_err("[i] vmxoff has failed!\n");
    asm volatile("vmxoff_finish:\n");

    printk("<1> vmxoff complete\n");
    return !(vmxoff_success);
}

static u8 do_vmwrite(u32 field, u64 val)
{
    u8 error;

    __asm __volatile ( "clc; vmwrite %%rax, %%rdx; setna %0"
            : "=q"( error ) : "a"( val), "d"( field ) : "cc");
    return error;
}

static void do_vmwrite16(unsigned long field, u16 value)
{
    do_vmwrite(field, value);
}

static void do_vmwrite32(unsigned long field, u32 value)
{
    do_vmwrite(field, value);
}

static void do_vmwrite64(unsigned long field, u64 value)
{
    do_vmwrite(field, value);
}

static void initialize_16bit_host_guest_state(void)
{
    unsigned long field,field1;
    u16         value;
    field = VMX_HOST_ES_SEL;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_ES_SEL;
    asm ("movw %%es, %%ax\n"
            :"=a"(value)
        );
    do_vmwrite16(field,value);
    do_vmwrite16(field1,value);

    field = VMX_HOST_CS_SEL;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_CS_SEL;
    asm ("movw %%cs, %%ax\n"
            : "=a"(value));
    do_vmwrite16(field,value);
    do_vmwrite16(field1,value);

    field = VMX_HOST_SS_SEL;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_SS_SEL;
    asm ("movw %%ss, %%ax\n"
            : "=a"(value));
    do_vmwrite16(field,value);
    do_vmwrite16(field1,value);

    field = VMX_HOST_DS_SEL;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_DS_SEL;
    asm ("movw %%ds, %%ax\n"
            : "=a"(value));
    do_vmwrite16(field,value);
    do_vmwrite16(field1,value);

    field = VMX_HOST_FS_SEL;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_FS_SEL;
    asm ("movw %%fs, %%ax\n"
            : "=a"(value));
    do_vmwrite16(field,value);
    do_vmwrite16(field1,value);

    field = VMX_HOST_GS_SEL;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_GS_SEL;
    asm ("movw %%gs, %%ax\n"
            : "=a"(value));
    do_vmwrite16(field,value);
    do_vmwrite16(field1,value);

    field = VMX_HOST_TR_SEL;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_TR_SEL;
    asm("str %%ax\n" : "=a"(tr_sel));
    do_vmwrite16(field,tr_sel);
    do_vmwrite16(field1,tr_sel);

    field = VMX_GUEST_LDTR_SEL;
    asm("sldt %%ax\n" : "=a"(value));
    do_vmwrite16(field,value);
}

static void initialize_64bit_control(void)
{
    unsigned long field;
    u64         value;

    field = VMX_IO_BITMAP_A_FULL;
    io_bitmap_a_phy_region = __pa(io_bitmap_a_region);
    value = io_bitmap_a_phy_region;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field = VMX_IO_BITMAP_B_FULL;
    io_bitmap_b_phy_region = __pa(io_bitmap_b_region);
    value = io_bitmap_b_phy_region;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field = VMX_MSR_BITMAP_FULL;
    msr_bitmap_phy_region = __pa(msr_bitmap_region);
    value = msr_bitmap_phy_region;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field = VMX_VIRTUAL_APIC_PAGE_ADDR_FULL;
    virtual_apic_page_phy_region = __pa(virtual_apic_page);
    value = virtual_apic_page_phy_region;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field = VMX_EXECUTIVE_VMCS_PTR_FULL;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field = VMX_TSC_OFFSET_FULL;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);
}

static void initialize_64bit_host_guest_state(void)
{
    unsigned long field;
    u64         value;
    field = VMX_VMS_LINK_PTR_FULL;
    value = 0xffffffffffffffffull;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);
    field = VMX_GUEST_IA32_DEBUGCTL_FULL;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);
}

static void initialize_32bit_control(void)
{
    unsigned long field;
    u32         value;

    field = VMX_PIN_VM_EXEC_CONTROLS;
    value = 0x1e;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_PROC_VM_EXEC_CONTROLS;
    value = 0x0401e172 ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_EXCEPTION_BITMAP;
    value = 0xffffffff ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_PF_EC_MASK;
    value = 0x0 ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_PF_EC_MATCH;
    value = 0 ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_CR3_TARGET_COUNT;
    value = 0 ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_EXIT_CONTROLS;
    value = 0x36fff ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_EXIT_MSR_STORE_COUNT;
    value = 0 ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_EXIT_MSR_LOAD_COUNT;
    value = 0 ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_ENTRY_CONTROLS;
    value = 0x13ff ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_ENTRY_MSR_LOAD_COUNT;
    value = 0 ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_ENTRY_INT_INFO_FIELD;
    value = 0 ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_ENTRY_EXCEPTION_EC;
    value = 0 ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_ENTRY_INSTR_LENGTH;
    value = 0 ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_TPR_THRESHOLD;
    value = 0 ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);
}

static void initialize_32bit_host_guest_state(void)
{
    unsigned long field;
    struct desc_ptr  xdesc;
    u64      value;
    s64     *host_gdt = NULL;
    s64         desc;
    s64         idtb;
    u64      gdtb;
    s64      realtrbase;
    u32      unusable_ar = 0x10000;
    u32      usable_ar;
    u16      sel_value;

    field = VMX_GUEST_ES_LIMIT;
    value = 0xffffffff ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_ES_ATTR;
    value = unusable_ar;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_CS_LIMIT;
    value = 0xffffffff ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    asm ("movw %%cs, %%ax\n"
            : "=a"(sel_value));
    asm("lar %%eax,%%eax\n" :"=a"(usable_ar) :"a"(sel_value));
    usable_ar = usable_ar >> 8;
    usable_ar &= 0xf0ff; //clear bits 11:8

    field = VMX_GUEST_CS_ATTR;
    do_vmwrite32(field,usable_ar);
    value = do_vmread(field);

    field = VMX_GUEST_SS_LIMIT;
    value = 0xffffffff ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    asm ("movw %%ss, %%ax\n"
            : "=a"(sel_value));
    asm("lar %%eax,%%eax\n" :"=a"(usable_ar) :"a"(sel_value));
    usable_ar = usable_ar >> 8;
    usable_ar &= 0xf0ff; //clear bits 11:8

    field = VMX_GUEST_SS_ATTR;
    do_vmwrite32(field,usable_ar);

    field = VMX_GUEST_DS_LIMIT;
    value = 0xffffffff ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_DS_ATTR;
    value = unusable_ar;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_FS_LIMIT;
    value = 0xffffffff ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_FS_ATTR;
    value = unusable_ar;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_GS_LIMIT;
    value = 0xffffffff ;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_GS_ATTR;
    value = unusable_ar;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_LDTR_LIMIT;
    value = 0x0;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_LDTR_ATTR;
    value = unusable_ar;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_TR_LIMIT;
    asm volatile("mov %%rax, %%rax"
            :
            :"a"(tr_sel)
            );
    asm("lsl %%eax, %%eax\n" :"=a"(value));
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    asm("lar %%eax,%%eax\n" :"=a"(usable_ar) :"a"(tr_sel));
    usable_ar = usable_ar >> 8;

    field = VMX_GUEST_TR_ATTR;
    do_vmwrite32(field,usable_ar);

    asm(" sgdt %0 ": "=m" (xdesc));
    value = xdesc.size & 0x0ffff;
    gdtb = xdesc.address; //base

    field = VMX_GUEST_GDTR_LIMIT;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_GDTR_BASE;
    do_vmwrite64(field,gdtb);
    field = VMX_HOST_GDTR_BASE;
    do_vmwrite64(field,gdtb);

    host_gdt = (s64 *)gdtb;
    desc = host_gdt[ (tr_sel >> 3) + 0 ];
    realtrbase = ((desc >> 32)&0xFF000000)|((desc >> 16)&0x00FFFFFF);
    desc = host_gdt[ (tr_sel >> 3) + 1 ];
    desc <<= 48;    // maneuver to insure 'canonical' addressing
    realtrbase |= (desc >> 16)&0xFFFFFFFF00000000;
    field = VMX_HOST_TR_BASE;
    do_vmwrite64(field,realtrbase);

    field = VMX_GUEST_TR_BASE;
    do_vmwrite64(field,realtrbase);

    asm("sidt %0\n" : "=m"(xdesc));
    value = xdesc.size & 0x0ffff;
    idtb = xdesc.address; //base

    field = VMX_GUEST_IDTR_LIMIT;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_IDTR_BASE;
    do_vmwrite64(field,idtb);
    field = VMX_HOST_IDTR_BASE;
    do_vmwrite64(field,idtb);

    field = VMX_GUEST_INTERRUPTIBILITY_INFO;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_ACTIVITY_STATE;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    field = VMX_GUEST_SMBASE;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);

    rdmsrl_safe(0x174, &value);
    field  = VMX_HOST_IA32_SYSENTER_CS;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);
    field = VMX_GUEST_IA32_SYSENTER_CS;
    do_vmwrite32(field,value);
}

static void initialize_naturalwidth_control(void)
{
    unsigned long field;
    u64         value;

    field = VMX_CR0_MASK;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);
    field = VMX_CR4_MASK;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field = VMX_CR0_READ_SHADOW;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field = VMX_CR4_READ_SHADOW;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field = VMX_CR3_TARGET_0;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field = VMX_CR3_TARGET_1;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field = VMX_CR3_TARGET_2;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field = VMX_CR3_TARGET_3;
    value = 0;
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);
}

static void initialize_naturalwidth_host_guest_state(void)
{
    unsigned long field,field1;
    u64         value;
    int      fs_low;
    int      gs_low;

    field =  VMX_HOST_CR0;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_CR0;
    asm ("movq %%cr0, %%rax\n"
            :"=a"(value)
        );
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);

    field =  VMX_HOST_CR3;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_CR3;
    asm ("movq %%cr3, %%rax\n"
            :"=a"(value)
        );
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);

    field =  VMX_HOST_CR4;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_CR4;
    asm ("movq %%cr4, %%rax\n"
            :"=a"(value)
        );
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);

    value=0;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_ES_BASE;
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_CS_BASE;
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_SS_BASE;
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_DS_BASE;
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_LDTR_BASE;
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);

    value = 0;
    field =  VMX_HOST_FS_BASE;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_FS_BASE;

    asm volatile("mov $0xc0000100, %rcx\n");
    asm volatile("rdmsr\n" :"=a"(fs_low) : :"%rdx");
    //asm volatile ("mov %%rax, %0\n" : :"m"(fs_low) :"memory");
    asm volatile ("shl $32, %%rdx\n" :"=d"(value));
    value|=fs_low;
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    value = 0;
    field =  VMX_HOST_GS_BASE;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_GS_BASE;
    asm volatile("mov $0xc0000101, %rcx\n");
    asm volatile("rdmsr\n" :"=a"(gs_low) : :"%rdx");
    //asm volatile ("mov %%rax, %0\n" : :"m"(gs_low) :"memory");
    asm volatile ("shl $32, %%rdx\n" :"=d"(value));
    value|=gs_low;
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field1 = VMX_GUEST_DR7;
    value = 0x400;
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);

    field = VMX_HOST_RSP;
    field1 = VMX_GUEST_RSP;
    asm ("movq %%rsp, %%rax\n"
            :"=a"(value)
        );
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    /*
       field1 = VMX_GUEST_RIP;
       value = (u64) guest_entry_code;
       do_vmwrite64(field1,value);

       field1 = VMX_HOST_RIP;
       value  = (u64) handle_vmexit;
       do_vmwrite64(field1,value); */


    field1 = VMX_GUEST_RFLAGS;
    asm volatile("pushfq\n");
    asm volatile("popq %0\n" :"=m"(value)::"memory");
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);

    field1 = VMX_GUEST_PENDING_DEBUG_EXCEPT;
    value = 0x0;
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);

    field1 = VMX_GUEST_IA32_SYSENTER_ESP;
    field  = VMX_HOST_IA32_SYSENTER_ESP;
    rdmsrl_safe(0x176, &value);
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);

    field1 = VMX_GUEST_IA32_SYSENTER_EIP;
    field =  VMX_HOST_IA32_SYSENTER_EIP;
    rdmsrl_safe(0x175, &value);
    do_vmwrite64(field1,value);
    do_vmwrite64(field,value);
}

static void initialize_guest_vmcs(void)
{
    initialize_16bit_host_guest_state();
    initialize_64bit_control();
    initialize_64bit_host_guest_state();
    initialize_32bit_control();
    initialize_naturalwidth_control();
    initialize_32bit_host_guest_state();
    initialize_naturalwidth_host_guest_state();
}

/* Allocate a 4K region for vmxon */
static void allocate_vmxon_region(void)
{
    vmxon_region = kmalloc(MYPAGE_SIZE,GFP_KERNEL);
}

/* Allocate a 4K vmcs region for the guest */
static void allocate_vmcs_region(void)
{
    vmcs_guest_region  =  kmalloc(MYPAGE_SIZE,GFP_KERNEL);
    io_bitmap_a_region =  kmalloc(MYPAGE_SIZE,GFP_KERNEL);
    io_bitmap_b_region =  kmalloc(MYPAGE_SIZE,GFP_KERNEL);
    msr_bitmap_region  =  kmalloc(MYPAGE_SIZE,GFP_KERNEL);
    virtual_apic_page  =  kmalloc(MYPAGE_SIZE,GFP_KERNEL);
    //Initialize data structures
    memset(vmcs_guest_region, 0, MYPAGE_SIZE);
    memset(io_bitmap_a_region, 0, MYPAGE_SIZE);
    memset(io_bitmap_b_region, 0, MYPAGE_SIZE);
    memset(msr_bitmap_region, 0, MYPAGE_SIZE);
    memset(virtual_apic_page, 0, MYPAGE_SIZE);
}

/* Dealloc vmxon region*/
static void deallocate_vmxon_region(void)
{
    if (vmxon_region) {
        printk("<1> freeing allocated vmxon region!\n");
        kfree(vmxon_region);
        vmxon_region = NULL;
    }
}

/* Dealloc vmcs guest region*/
static void deallocate_vmcs_region(void)
{
    if (vmcs_guest_region) {
        printk("<1> freeing allocated vmcs region!\n");
        kfree(vmcs_guest_region);
        vmcs_guest_region = NULL;
    }
    if (io_bitmap_a_region) {
        printk("<1> freeing allocated io bitmapA region!\n");
        kfree(io_bitmap_a_region);
        io_bitmap_a_region = NULL;
    }
    if (io_bitmap_b_region) {
        printk("<1> freeing allocated io bitmapB region!\n");
        kfree(io_bitmap_b_region);
        io_bitmap_b_region = NULL;
    }
    if (msr_bitmap_region) {
        printk("<1> freeing allocated msr bitmap region!\n");
        kfree(msr_bitmap_region);
        msr_bitmap_region = NULL;
    }
    if (virtual_apic_page) {
        printk("<1> freeing allocated virtual apic page region!\n");
        kfree(virtual_apic_page);
        virtual_apic_page = NULL;
    }
}

/*initialize revision id*/
static void vmxon_setup_revid(void)
{
    rdmsrl_safe(vmx_msr_addr, &vmx_rev_id);
}

void turn_on_vmxe( void *dummy )
{
    u64 crx[16];

    asm ( "mov %%cr4, %%rax \n"\
          "mov %%rax, %0\n" : "=m" (crx[id]) ::"ax");
    if ((crx[id] & (1 << 13)) == 0) {
        asm (   " mov  %%cr4, %%rax     \n"\
                " bts  $13, %%rax       \n"\
                " mov  %%rax, %%cr4     " ::: "ax" );

        asm (   "mov %%cr4, %%rax \n"\
                "mov %%rax, %0\n" : "=m" (crx[id]) ::"ax");
    } else {
        pr_warn("VMXE in CR4 already been set, VT-X may be used by other VMM\n");
    }
}

void turn_off_vmxe( void *dummy )
{
    u64 crx[16];

    asm ( "mov %%cr4, %%rax \n"\
          "mov %%rax, %0\n" : "=m" (crx[id]) ::"ax");
    crx[id] &= ~(1 << 13);
    asm (   " mov  %%cr4, %%rax     \n"\
            " btr  $13, %%rax       \n"\
            " mov  %%rax, %%cr4     " ::: "ax" );
}

static void vmxon_exit(void)
{
    if (vmxon_success == 1) {
        printk("<1> Machine in vmxon: Attempting vmxoff\n");
        do_vmclear();
        do_vmxoff();
        vmxon_success = 0;
    }
    turn_off_vmxe(NULL);
    deallocate_vmcs_region();
    deallocate_vmxon_region();
}

static int vmxon_init(void)
{
    unsigned long   field_1;
    u32  value_1    =0;
    int  cpuid_leaf =1;
    int  cpuid_ecx  =0;
    u64  msr3a_value = 0;
    u32     lo[2], hi[2];
    u64  start, end;

    printk("<1> In vmxon\n");

    asm volatile("cpuid\n\t"
            :"=c"(cpuid_ecx)
            :"a"(cpuid_leaf)
            :"%rbx","%rdx");

    if ((cpuid_ecx >> CPUID_VMX_BIT) & 1) {
        printk("<1> VMX supported CPU.\n");
    } else {
        printk("<1> VMX not supported by CPU. Not doing anything\n");
        goto finish_here;
    }

    rdmsrl_safe(feature_control_msr_addr, &msr3a_value);

    if (msr3a_value & 1) {
        if ((msr3a_value >> 2) & 1) {
            printk("MSR 0x3A:Lock bit is on.VMXON bit is on.OK\n");
        } else {
            printk("MSR 0x3A:Lock bit is on.VMXONbit is off.Cannot do vmxon\n");
            goto finish_here;
        }
    } else {
        printk("MSR 0x3A: Lock bit is not on. Not doing anything\n");
        goto finish_here;
    }

    allocate_vmxon_region();

    if (vmxon_region == NULL) {
        printk("<1> Error allocating vmxon region\n");
        vmxon_exit();
        vmxon_success = -ENOMEM;
        return vmxon_success;
    }

    allocate_vmcs_region();
    alloc_failure = (vmcs_guest_region == NULL)  ||
                    (io_bitmap_a_region == NULL) ||
                    (io_bitmap_b_region == NULL) ||
                    (msr_bitmap_region == NULL)  ||
                    (virtual_apic_page == NULL);

    if (alloc_failure) {
        printk("<1> Error allocating vmcs guest region\n");
        vmxon_exit();
        vmptrld_success = -ENOMEM;
        return vmptrld_success;
    }

    vmxon_setup_revid();
    vmxon_phy_region = virt_to_phys(vmxon_region);
    memset(vmxon_region, 0, MYPAGE_SIZE);
    memcpy(vmxon_region, &vmx_rev_id, 4); //copy revision id to vmxon region

    turn_on_vmxe(NULL);

    do_vmxon();

    vmcs_phy_region = virt_to_phys(vmcs_guest_region);
    memset(vmcs_guest_region, 0, MYPAGE_SIZE);
    memcpy(vmcs_guest_region, &vmx_rev_id, 4); //copy revision id to vmcs region

    do_vmclear();
    do_vmptrld();

    initialize_guest_vmcs();

    //host rip
    asm ("movq $0x6c16, %rdx");
    asm ("movq $vmexit_handler, %rax");
    asm ("vmwrite %rax, %rdx");

    //guest rip
    asm ("movq $0x681e, %rdx");
    asm ("movq $guest_entry_point, %rax");
    asm ("vmwrite %rax, %rdx");

    printk("<1> Doing vmlaunch now..\n");

    asm volatile (
            "vmlaunch                      \n"\
            "jbe vmexit_handler            \n" \
            "nop                           \n" \
            "guest_entry_point:            \n" \
            "   vmcall                     \n" \
            "   ud2                        \n" \
            "vmexit_handler: \n");

    asm volatile("sti");

    printk("<1> After vmexit\n");

    field_1 = VMX_EXIT_REASON;
    value_1 = do_vmread(field_1);
    printk("<1> Guest VMexit reason: 0x%x\n",value_1);

finish_here:
    vmxon_exit(); //do vmxoff
    printk("<1> Done\n");
    return 0;
}

static void vmxon_exit_dummy(void)
{
    printk("In Function %s\n", __func__);
}

module_init(vmxon_init);
module_exit(vmxon_exit_dummy);
```

Without calling 'vmlaunch', module loading/unloading are OK.
Please help check if there is anything wrong.

Comment: The code to set the host rip is commented out.

Comment: Don’t use separate asm statements to initialize registers. The compiler can insert other instruction between, overwriting the registers. Use input and output constraints.

Comment: Here is the setting of host_rip.
    asm ("movq $0x6c16, %rdx");
    asm ("movq $vmexit_handler, %rax");
    asm ("vmwrite %rax, %rdx");

And by dumping the VMCS, the host_RIP is set to the vmexit_handler.

Comment: And i just fixed a bug in Mohan's codes, where IA32_SYSENTER_RIP/ESP are not correct numbered. With the fix, it can still hit the hang.

Comment: HOST_RSP is set to the current value of RSP inside one of the helper functions. When the guest exits, the exit handler behaves as if RSP hasn't changed. In particular, after printing some trace, it tries to return using a bogus stack pointer. (Unless all the helper functions are inlined.) It is probably not very robust to have the vmexit handler in the middle of another function.

Comment: I move the setting of HOST_RSP to the before of vmlaunch in the asm stuff, this time, it worked almost perfectly. Except for a random error like this, "[53597.888996] <1> Done
[53597.889345] insmod[3779]: segfault at fffffffff40e6718 ip 00007f41f3edca8d sp 00007ffc1a1d44a0 error 5 in ld-2.23.so[7f41f3ecd000+26000]". Sometimes, this error happened, sometimes it did NOT. Still checking if anything wrong. Thx

Comment: @prl. I struggled with this module for these days, tried lots of ways/changes to fix the error reported against ld-2.23.so. Just 5 minutes ago, I think i really fixed it, by following your first comments. I.e. changing the getting of FS_BASE/GS_BASE by using a single ASM statement (rdmsrl_safe). After this change, I looped 100 seconds to load/unload the module, no any error hit.  So I would like to vote for your first comments as the right answer. Thanks a lot for your help.